# Entityframework entity update only works when running in debug mode

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I have 4 related entities as shown below

```
public class VariantOption
{
     public virtual Variant Variant { get; set; }
 }

public class ProductVariant 
{
   public virtual Product  Product { get; set; }
   public virtual Variant  Variant { get; set; }
   public virtual VariantOption DefaultVariantOption { get; set; }
   public virtual List<VariantOption> Selected_Options { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
   public virtual List<ProductVariant> ProductVariants { get; set; }
}

public class Variant
{
   public virtual List<VariantOption> Var_Options { get; set; }
   public virtual VariantOption DefaultVariantOption { get; set; }
}
```

In the update method, I do something like

```
 public bool UpdateProductVariant(ProductVariant productVariant){
      var dbProductVariant = context.ProductVariant.Find(productVariant.Id);

      dbProductVariant.DefaultVariantOption = context.VariantOptions.Find(productVariant.DefaultVariantOption.Id);
      dbProductVariant.VariantOptions.Clear();
      dbProductVariant.VariantOptions = 
        productVariant.VariantOptions.Select(x => context.VariantOptions.Find(x.Id)).ToList();

      context.SaveChanges();
 }
```

The issue is this

1. If a variant option is present in both the list and as defaultvalue, the new defaultvalue is saved
2. If a default value does not exist in the options list, the new defaultvalue is not saved
3. If a default value does not exist in the options list, but application is run in debug mode with breakpoint on the update method, the new defaultvalue is saved

Comment: Please tag the appropriate EF version.

Comment: thanks... changed to ef 6

Comment: Do you mean that `ProductVariant.DefaultVariantOption` isn't saved? (If so, I don't understand how it could be saved at all, because you don't modify the property anywhere).

Comment: yes it is not saved ... I did not write out the entire method ... Thanks for the comment. Ill include a line to show default variant option being edited